# TypeScript compiler options "target" and "useDefineForClassFields" are set to "ES2022"

Tags: node.js, typescript

Whenever my project runs, I get this error:

```
TypeScript compiler options "target" and "useDefineForClassFields" are set to "ES2022" and "false" respectively by the Angular CLI. To control ECMA version and features use the Browerslist configuration.
```

I don't understand the intricacies of Node, TypeScript, etc. - is there an easy way to resolve this? Here's what I've tried...

From what I've seen, you need Node 16+ to fix this, but I have 16.8.1 - so that's not fixing it.

So I go to `tsconfig.json` and update everything to ES2022. Then I get:

[image]

I don't know what is limiting this - Node? TypeScript? Something else?

In Project Properties, I find this:

[image]

Does that mean I can't use ES2022? If not, how to I upgrade to get ES2022? I'm just looking for a simple fix to upgrade whatever is required to resolve this...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it.

`npm install -g typescript`

Updated from 4.0.3 to 5.1.3